# create database table and manage activity with time

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

There are two types of users One is Free and the other is Paid user. As a user with the role FreeUser, I can have only 3 open (Time not over yet) activities, as PayingUser unlimited. How to manage this in a database table

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can you represent inheritance in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579079/how-can-you-represent-inheritance-in-a-database)

Answer (score 0):

```
UserType
  usertypeid, PK
  usertype, NN

User
  userid, PK
  username, NN
  usertype, FK UserType.usertypeid
```

For the activities, you have a couple options.

- store the activities counter in the user session.
- store the activities counter in the database.  That can be a simple counter in the users table
- in the event you have a high availability configuration (more than 1 application server), you will have to share sessions, or store the counter in the database to ensure your counter survives a server going down.

Regardless, the logic behind the management of activities is handled by the application.